# How do I print a string's characters in a diagonal pattern?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that reads a string from the user and prints the string's characters in a diagonal pattern. I set the maximum length of the string as 50 characters. The program can print the characters in a diagonal pattern, but it doesn't print the characters correctly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
  int i = 0, j = 0, m;
  char c[50];

  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf("%c", c);

  m = sizeof(c) / sizeof(c[0]);

  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (j == i) {
        printf("%c", c[i-1]);
      } else {
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why can't use `strlen()` and to print in a diagonal format print newline after the character is printed and do print incremental spaces

Comment: `m=sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);` this is redundant, you already hardcoded the length (50).

Comment: `scanf("%c",c);` input only one character.

Comment: is this a coding problem you were given for an interview question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i=0,s=0;
    char c[50];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",c);

    while(c[i] != '\0')
        {
            s = i;
            while(s--)
            printf(" ");
            printf("%c\n",c[i]);
             i++; 
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggested `char c[51];`.. `scanf("%50s", c);` `printf("%*c\n", i+1, c[i]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Cool just going by the code I saw I went this way to show how this can be done. Again with your code you need to explain what `%*` does I avoided that :)